# Can a passenger refused entry due to lack of papers claim a refund from the airline?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, passports

A relative of mine traveled to Spain with a Turkish passport from South America. She didn't knew she needed a visa for Spain and was allowed boarding by the airline.

Upon arrival she was held in a "detention room" uncommunicated for 24 hours (she was treated well by Spanish authorities though) until she was deported for failing to have the correct documents. 
As standard procedure she was assigned a lawyer who told her that airlines pay penalties when this happens.

My question is, can she request a refund for being allowed boarding despite being inadmissible?

Comment: Check the fine print for the ticket purchase. Almost certainly, it will say somewhere that having the appropriate documents is the passenger's responsibility.

Comment: Was Spain her destination or was she connecting?

Comment: @Johns-305 it was her destination

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Yes, I am sure it does...but we know they put everything in there. The lawyer was very insistent about the penalty on behalf of the state towards the airline (he said something about $7000 euros)

Comment: @JordanBelf Was she actually fined by the airline? I have a feeling that this practice (passing on airline fines to the customer) is not legal. But she can't sue for being allowed to board in general, checking she has the right documents for entry was her responsibility.

Comment: @MJeffryes No, after the event no one from the airline communicated with her nor money was requested by the airline (at least yet. This happened on Wednesday). Regarding documentation. I believe airlines have the responsibility to validate passengers before boarding. That is why it will be fined by the state. But I might be wrong.

Comment: Countries impose on airlines a duty to the country to only bring in properly documented passengers, That is a normal condition for being permitted to operate international flights into a country. The question is whether the airline also has a duty to the passenger to prevent boarding without proper documentation.

Comment: @JordanBelf She cannot be compensated for being allowed boarding, as check-in staff are **not** liable to her in that regard. **But**, also don't let the airline charge her, which low-cost carriers often try to do. If they suddenly charge her card, she should dispute it with the card provider

Comment: @Crazydre you mean charge her the penalties? Or charge her the ticket?

Comment: @JordanBelf She should be charged **nothing** other than what she's paid already. They're meant to give her a free seat for the deportation, unless she voluntarily buys her own ticket elsewhere

Comment: @Crazydre thanks. Yes, that is exactly what will happen, but I was not aware they could try to charge her anything other than the ticket she paid and couldn't use. Also, now she can't even change it because they allowed her boarding and the ticket is obviously used. That is why I want to know if a refund is possible.

Comment: @JordanBelf Like I said, no refund is possible, but she's not supposed to pay anything further. Nothing more, nothing less, but again Ryanair and WIZZ will routinely try and charge the passenger for their penalties, in which case, again, dispute it with the bank/card issuer. She may want to lock her card for unsecured transactions, as that *may* prevent them from charging her

Comment: @Crazydre thanks a lot for your input. In this case it was Air Europa.

Comment: @JordanBelf Should be OK then; most likely they changed her return ticket for the deportation, so that both legs are effectively used up.

Comment: It is not obvious that passengers have a right to a free seat for deportations. Such cases have been fought in German courts and the rulings are in favour of the airlines. They are allowed to claim fines and other costs related to the deportation (e.g. a new ticket) from the passenger. This is not only done by low-cost carriers. Lufthansa operates also with the same policy.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo in this case she already had a return ticket. But one can argue that due to the airline error she couldn't reprogram her flight for a later date.

Comment: @Crazydre under ICAO rules, airlines can recover the cost of transporting the rejected traveller to a destination that will accept them.  If the original ticket does not cover this cost, the excess can be charged to the passenger.

Comment: “5.10 When a person is found inadmissible and is returned to the aircraft operator for transport away from the territory of the State, the aircraft operator shall not be precluded from recovering from such person any transportation costs involved in his removal.“ https://www.un.org/sc/ctc/news/document/icao-best-practices-annex-9-chapter-5-inadmissible-persons-and-deportees/

Comment: @Crazydre so no, the seat is not meant to be free.

Comment: @Moo I am not sure that applies to mistakes made by the airline. In this case in particular, boarding a passenger without a visa is a mistake from the airline (thus the fine they have to pay). I think that rule might apply to other, not so obvious, scenarios.

Comment: @JordanBelf the eligibility of entry remains the travellers responsibility, so yes it does apply in this instance - the checks put in place by the airlines are only there for the airlines sake, they do not convey any entitlement or duty of care to the passenger.  If the passenger is inadmissible, this rule applies.

Comment: @Moo I don't believe that is the case. Because that wouldn't explain why the spanish government is collecting a fine from the airline when they make this mistake. For what I understand and was explained by the lawyer, the airlines are given the task of boarding only valid passengers.

Comment: @JordanBelf in the link I give above, the topic of issuing of a fine to the airline and the recovery of transport costs by the airline are dealt with separately, with the fine being mitigated if the airline can demonstrate they carried out documentation procedures correctly.  Therefor, the two things are not linked - the airline can be subject to a fine for not following procedure and the airline can also recover transportation costs from the traveller.  It applies in this circumstance.

Comment: @JordanBelf read the link - the lawyer you spoke to sounds like a poor lawyer or one who did not explain the situation fully. The airlines duty of care in the regard of properly documented travellers is to the destination state, not the traveller.  The airline receives a fine because they boarded the ineligible traveller, but that does not preclude them from recovering the cost of transportation back from the destination.

Comment: Thanks @moo for now I will follow the instructions from a lawyer and different government officials which operate under the law which goes above an association T&C.

Comment: @JordanBelf the above link is to the UN International Civil Aviation Organisation - it’s not an “associations T&Cs”.  It’s the rules of international aviation transport by which all UN members adhere to.

Comment: @moo well then someone might be following a different set of rules because my relative was not charged a dime for the ticket back to South America and as far as I am aware the airline was fined by the Spanish government. Anyway there's no point arguing I just wanted to know if anyone knew of any previews case similar to this one. Let's see how it develops. Thanks for your time

Comment: @JordanBelf fines and transportation costs are two entirely different things - I’m referring to the latter in my comments.  Whether fines can be passed on has been contentious in many jurisdictions and airlines generally do not pass them on - but every case I know where someone has disputed the transportation costs has resulted in a loss for the traveller.  Whether the airline decides to recover transportation costs is entirely up to the airline - the rules say that they cannot be precluded from doing so, not that they must do so.

Comment: @JordanBelf but if you want an answer to your title question about a refund, the answer is “no” - the airline fulfilled its contract to your relative, it got them to the destination.  It then flew them back from the destination.  The fact that your relative was refused entry is none of the airlines concern or responsibility (to your relative).  No refund is due here.

Comment: ...and now the question was closed. Now I remember why I left the community. This question is not a duplicate to the one @jonathannreez claims as the question asks about a refund not if airlines should or shouldn't check for visas. It is very unfortunate since this was a very constructive discussion which could have benefited many users.

Comment: Not a duplicate, as this is about the implications for passengers denied entry, not about the airline's responsibility.

Comment: @Crazydre the question in the post is only about financial questions. If edited it could be a new question. As is it is a definite duplicate.

Comment: @JonathanReez The suggested duplicate treats the same issue from the airline's perspective, but does not cover the passenger's perspective, i.e. whether they are to be refunded by the airline

Comment: @jonathanreez so according to your decision I should be able to find the answer to my question over there. Could you point it to me? (Hint: A private company t&c is not the law, therefore not the answer) On the other hand something like what @ moo wrote here seems much more robust and can't be found over there. The reason is quite simple.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> can she request a refund for being allowed boarding despite being inadmissible?

No.  Eligibility for entry into the destination and any intermediate stops is solely and universally the responsibility of the traveller, and as such the airline carried out their contractual obligation to the traveller in transporting them to the destination and back again.  The refusal of entry at the destination is not the responsibility of the airline.

It’s true that airlines have an obligation under ICAO rules to the destination state (either ultimate destination or transit stops) to not present ineligible travellers, which is why they often check documentation and eligibility before travel begins, but this obligation does not extend from the airline to the traveller.  Airlines can receive fines from states for each ineligible traveller they present where suitable checks have not been carried out, but this infers no responsibility to the traveller at all.

As such, no refund is due - the airline carried out their part of the contract without issue.