# Who is responsible for onward travel after being denied entry to a country?

Tags: compensation, denial-of-entry

I was booked with Qatar Airlines from Muscat to Bangkok, via Doha.  When checking in at Muscat Qatar ground staff checked my documentation for my flight to Bangkok.  I had the ‘fit to fly medical’, the required insurance but I did not have a work permit, instead I had an official document stating I was in a domestic relationship in Thailand and a hospital appointment for the birth of my Son.  I was asked if I had a work permit and I told Qatar staff I did not.  Discussions were made between staff and I was checked in and handed boarding cards to Doha and for Bangkok.

Again, at the boarding gate in Doha for the Bangkok flight, I was asked again if I had a work permit to which I replied “no” and I produced my documents again and was allowed to board the Bangkok flight.

Upon arrival in Bangkok, I was denied entry into the Kingdom of Thailand as I do not hold a work permit.  I was escorted to the immigration office and told by Qatar staff that I had to pay for my own flight to the UK.

This was all very upsetting and degrading for me as I can not be there for the birth of my son and I was treated like I criminal as I was deemed to be a security risk.  Qatar stat refused to give me my passport back until my final destination.

I was forced to sit at the back of the plane on both flights and accompanied to the boarding gate by Qatar ground staff.  The staff in Doha were not discreet!  As he was stood in the que with a document stating I was a deportee for everyone to see.

On top of this, I had to spend 2/3 hours in Doha, I could not get any food or water as I was refused my boarding card!  I requested to be escorted to a restaurant but this was denied as it seemed the staff member was too busy sitting relaxing in an office!

I found the manager at the boarding gate in Bangkok to be very rude, she refused to give me her name!  There was no compassion shown to me as I was going to be with my newborn son and partner.

I would like to know why I was allowed to board 2 separate flights with no work permit.  Had I known this was required I would not have attempted to travel to Thailand!

As soon as I returned to UK I checked both CAAT & IATA and they both state Work Permit was required!

Also why did I have to pay for an onward flight to the UK when Qatar failed in their ‘Duty of Care’ by allowing me to travel with insufficient documents.  The responsibility for the cost of my onward travel surely lies with Qatar?

Regards

Barry Mutch

Comment: You are always responsible for all needed paperwork. The airlines usually check because they are charged fines but they will try to get that money back from you if they have the chance. I am sure this is a duplicate question, I will try to find the other version.

Comment: From Qatar Airways website: “Qatar Airways cannot be held liable for any disruption to your travel plans resulting from incorrect travel documentation.” https://www.qatarairways.com/en-gb/visa-and-passport-requirements.html

Comment: You are mistaken in thinking that an airline has any duty of care to you for ensuring you fulfil the relevant entry requirements for a country, they do not.  That duty remains the sole responsibility of the traveller.  The checks the airline does is for their benefit, not yours.  Under IATA rules the airline can charge you for the cost of removing you from the port you were denied entry st.

Comment: See my comments on this question: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/152735/can-a-passenger-refused-entry-due-to-lack-of-papers-claim-a-refund-from-the-airl

Comment: You wouldn't need a work permit to enter Thailand. Thailand allows for visa-less entry for quite some nations, so your story seems... convoluted.

Comment: Did you have a return ticket? How long were you planning to stay? Have you overstayed there in the past?